# c#: with a Handler(.ashx) get post send with javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, get, handler, ashx

I am trying to get a string from a textbox in a .aspx page. When I debug my site jQuery.post is able to see the input value, but when I try to get the value in my handler, he is giving me NULL back. Anyone help!!!

JS:

```
CompanyName = $("#company").val();
jQuery.post('/CartHandler.ashx', { 'CompanyName': CompanyName });
```

ASHX:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string ImeTvrtke = context.Request.QueryString["CompanyName"];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make a POST request, the value is not sent as part of the query string. So don't look in the query string for it. Retrieve it like this:

```
string ImeTvrtke = context.Request["CompanyName"];
```

Alternatively if you wanted to be sent as part of the query string then use a GET request:

```
jQuery.get('/CartHandler.ashx', { 'CompanyName': CompanyName });
```

Comment: I tryed with GET, it's the same.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. Can you see the AJAX request being made in Fiddler?

Comment: When I post with jquery serialize, I am able to get in the handler the whole form, but I need only one string

Comment: This should work with only a single value. Maybe the code you have shown in your question is not the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get a posted parameter from the query string rather than the form it was posted from.

Try:

```
context.Request.Form["CompanyName"];
```

Or just:

```
context.Request["CompanyName"]
```

Comment: If you can't get the string, then your probably want the .Value of the Request[] / Request.Form[], apologies, I didn't understand that as your problem

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a post, you should look in the Request.Forms collection instead of the QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string ImeTvrtke = context.Request["CompanyName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this.... 
http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

This might help.....